# Auto renewable subscription does not have free trial period

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have the auto renewable subscription on the App Store Connect. It is only one in my app. It has been approved:

[image]

Also it has free trial period (the introductory price):
[image]

But to my regret on the device I see:

[image]

No trial period... I have already double checked the ProductID on the app - it is really the same as in App Store Connect. And the subscription is only one. Any help are appreciated.

Comment: For me, what you are saying doesn't add up.

Comment: @ElTomato for me either. This happens with the real account and with sandbox users. And also I can't delete the subscription because the app is in App Store.